# Python, who is calling my python module

Tags: python, cgi

I have one Python module that can be called by a CGI script (passing it information from a form) or from the command line (passing it options and arguments from the command line).
Is there a way to establish if the module has been called from the CGI script or from the command line ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do it:

```
import os
if os.environ.has_key('REQUEST_METHOD'):
    # You're being run as a CGI script.
else:
    # You're being run from the command line.
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a really bad design idea.  Your script should be designed to work independently of how it's called.  The calling programs should provide a uniform environment.

You'll be happiest if you design your scripts to work in exactly one consistent way.  Build things like this.

- myscript.py - the "real work" - defined in functions and classes.
- myscript_cgi.py - a CGI interface that imports myscript and uses the classes and functions.
- myscript_cli.py - the command-line interface that parses the command-line options, imports myscript, and uses the classes and functions.

A single script that does all three things (real work, cgi interface, cli interface) is usually a mistake.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice ! I will do as u suggested ...

P.S. I've started reading your book, I really lake it !!!


Bye